# Passing a local html page with querystring in windows phone

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get pdf.js to work locally on a windows phone app written in Xamarin but I can't understand why if I pass a url without any querystring it works:

```
url = "Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html"
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
PdfWebViewer.Source = uri;
```

The above displays the pdf.js viewer correctly but with no pdf file of course but if I change the url to:

```
url = "Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=test.pdf"
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
PdfWebViewer.Source = uri;
```

I just get a page not found. Note the javascript is enabled.

I've added the various web browser events to see if I could spot anything else, and when I call the url without a querystring, it calls the `Navigating` event followed by the `Navigated` event but as soon as I specify a querystring, it triggers the `Navigating` followed by `NavigationFailed` event but I can't see the error as the exception returned in `e.exception` is null.

Am I missing something?? Is this not allowed?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It may not be a problem with Xamarin as I've just tried the same thing in a WP8.1 using the `WebBrowser` control and I get exactly the same behaviour.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = True
    WebBrowser.Source = New Uri("/Html/Viewer.Html?file=1", UriKind.Relative)

End Sub
```

My Viewer.html is the most basic page you could have:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Test
  </body>
</html>
```

Get rid of the query string and the web browser will display Test. Any ideas??

Comment: What is PdfWebViewer?  Is it a Xamarin Forms webview, or a Windows Phone webview or webbrowser?

Comment: It's the WebView from Xamarin but I have a renderer to a windows phone web browser. I've just noticed that the app is actually set to wp8.0. I probably should upgrade this to wp8.1 but I think it will still be the webbrowser rather than the webview. I don't know if Xamarin wp8.1 (non Silverlight) version.

Comment: what is the full path to test.pdf?

Comment: I could provide it, but I don't think that's the problem. I've modified the viewer.js to display an alert with the file obtained from the querystring and if I don't pass any parameter it displays the default one that came with pdf.js but the second I pass any parameters, it just gives me a "page not found", so it's not the path that the issue. If I called the following: .../viewer.html?file=1, with my alert it should display one but instead, I get a navigation error. It seems to have a problem handling a url with  querystring.

Comment: There's obviously a problem as I found this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213737/webbrowser-control-and-query-string-wp7 - I'll look into it some more and see what comes of it and then update this post.

Comment: @Jason, ok using the work-around from the link below worked, but now my pdf won't open when I pass this path: Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html#file=/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{3F3D90EF-3BA3-411C-961F-D1F9064CDD05}/local/Temp/TempPdf.pdf - Any ideas?